# go - Not enough arguments in call to "html/template".Must

Tags: html, go, arguments, render, template-engine

I write a wrapper function in Golang for rendering template from multiple files like this:

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}, tmpl... string) {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    for _,file:=range tmpl{
        file=filepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")
    }
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl...)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    templates:=template.Must(t)
    err = templates.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

When I run server from `main` function, the console throws an error:

`not enough arguments in call to "html/template".Must`

If I write like this:

`templates,err:=template.Must(t)`

It also throws the same error, plus:

`assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1`

I intend to use this function for a route handler in server:

```
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    files:=[]string{"base","index"}
    util.RenderTemplate(w, nil, files...)
}
```

`index.html` extends from `base.html` using template nesting

`base.html` template:

```
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charget="utf-8">
    <title>{{template "title".}}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{template "index".}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

And `index.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{{define "title"}}Homepage{{end}}
<body>
    {{define "index"}}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="../public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png">
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 33px; letter-spacing: 5px">Organize <br>Modern Knowledge<br> for Mankind</h2>
                    <p style="font-size: 20px;margin-top: 35px;letter-spacing: 4px">Consume, Colect and Revisit <br>Knowledge at Your Fingertips</p>
                    <a href="#" style="margin-top: 80px;display: inline-block;margin-left: -17px"><img src="../public/images/btn_get_chrome.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Did I miss something? I checked the prototype of `"html/template".Must` and didn't get what happened

Comment: You don't need to use `template.Must` here; you're doing the error checking on the previous lines.

Comment: @TimCooper I haven't got it

Comment: @TimCooper When I removed `templates`, and use `t.Execute`, I compile successfully, the server starts, and the browser displays when requesting `index` page

`open base: no such file or directory`

I already register static file handler

`http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))`

And `index` route handler in main

`http.HandleFunc("/",route.IndexHandler)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call ParseFiles and Must, you can call one or the other

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}, tmpl... string) {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    for _,file:=range tmpl{
        file=filepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")
    }
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl...)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err = t.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

I believe the func above should do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

`template.Must()` has this signature:

```
func Must(t *Template, err error) *Template
```

the arguments to `Must()` are "by coincidence" the same as the return values to `ParseFiles()` and `ParseGlob()` so you can use those functions inside `Must()` and have the effect that it panics, if the error is non-nil. So you can say

```
t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(....))
```

and don't care about the error checking. This is merely a convenience function, similar to all other `Must()` functions throughout the standard library, such as `regexp.MustCompile()`.

The implementation of `Must()` is straightforward:

```
func Must(t *Template, err error) *Template {
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    return t
}
```

See https://golang.org/src/text/template/helper.go?s=576:619#L11